# Filter with nested string array using odata

Tags: .net, odata

My backend is on .net. I have a model such as:

`class ChildModel { public string[] Values { get; set; } }`

`class ParentModel{ public ChildModel ChildModel {get; set;} }`

I want to filter data using odata from Child model.values.

I tried the followings:
`$filter=contains(ChildModel/Values,'Val1')`

`$filter=$expand=ChildModel($filter=Values/any(Values: Valueseq 'Val1'))`

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use something like this:

```
$filter=ChildModel/Values/any(r:r eq 'Val1')
```